# Seeking clarification on std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, std, forward

Referring to [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

For all the overloads, the return type has been specified as `T&&` (ignoring `constexpr`).

But in the description attached to the following example:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg) 
{
    // arg is always lvalue
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); // Forward as lvalue or as rvalue, depending on T
}
```

- If a call to wrapper() passes an rvalue std::string, then T is
  deduced to std::string (not std::string&, const std::string&, or
  std::string&&), and std::forward ensures that an rvalue reference is
  passed to foo.
- If a call to wrapper() passes a const lvalue
  std::string, then T is deduced to const std::string&, and
  std::forward ensures that a const lvalue reference is passed to foo.
- If a call to wrapper() passes a non-const lvalue std::string, then T 
  is deduced to std::string&, and std::forward ensures that a non-const
  lvalue reference is passed to foo.

In the two instances above after the first, an lvalue reference and not an rvalue reference (as implied by `T&&`, is this understanding correct?) has been documented as being passed to foo.

If the above understanding is correct, how come the return value has been specified as `T&&`?

Comment: `T&&` does not always mean a rvalue reference. I suggest to read  Scott Meyers article ["Universal References in C++11"](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: Take a look at how [reference collapsing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) work.

Comment: What else do you think the return value should be specified as?

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between

```cpp
void f1(int&& a) {}

template<class T>
void f2(T&& a) {}
```

The first version is defining `f1` to work on rvalues. The second version, on the other hand, is a template function accepting a universal (or in some references, forwarding) reference as its argument.

To understand the mechanics of `std::forward`, you should call `f2` with different arguments, as in:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T> void f2(T &&a) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main() {
  int a{5};

  f2(5);
  f2(a);

  return 0;
}
```

When you compile the code, say with `g++`, you get the following output from your program:

```
./a.out
void f2(T &&) [T = int]
void f2(T &&) [T = int &]
```

As you can see, in the first call `T` is deduced to be `int`, whereas in the second call it is deduced to be `int &`. Due to the reference collapsing rules, as already mentioned in the comments to your question, `T &&` will give you `T` whereas `T& &&` will give you `T&`. In short, you observing `T&&` as the return type does not mean that the functions return an rvalue reference. In fact, in the template functions, `&&` is like an identity operator. When combined with `T&`, it will give you `T&`; otherwise, it will give you `T`.

There is a [really nice talk](https://youtu.be/vwrXHznaYLA?t=33m50s) at CppCon2016 by Arthur O'Dwyer on this topic. Maybe you can have a look at it to understand the template type deduction rules, which will help you in clarifying the `std::forward` behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd try to explain the general case in as simple a way as I can (without omitting any details) as I was confused by `std::forward` for the longest time.

Let `[base-type]` refer to the unreferenced part of the parameter type (which can have other type descriptors like `const` but no `&`'s). These are all the official reference collapsing rules for free (i.e. undetermined) template parameters. The far left column represents the type of `T`.  The far right column represents the corresponding type of `T&` or `T&&` (i.e. type of `arg` in the template).

```
   Type of T              Type of arg
.     |                       |
.     v                       v
1 [base-type]   + &   => [base-type]&
2 [base-type]   + &&  => [base-type]&&
3 [base-type]&  + &   => [base-type]&
4 [base-type]&  + &&  => [base-type]&
5 [base-type]&& + &   => [base-type]&
6 [base-type]&& + &&  => [base-type]&&
```

When `arg` is specified as type `T&&`, only rules 2, 4, or 6 apply for type deduction.

If the passed `arg` has the form `[base-type]&&`, only rules 2 and 6 apply.  If rule 2 is used, `[base-type]` will be substituted for `T`.  If rule 6 is used `[base-type]&&` will be substituted for `T`.  These cases are practically identical as the return type, `T&&`, will be `[base-type]&&` in both cases.

```
Rule 2: T + && = [base-type] + && = [base-type]&&

Rule 6: T + && = [base-type]&& + && = [base-type]&&
```

From tests I've done, the compiler *always* choses `T` = `[base-type]` over `[base-type]&` or `[base-type]&&`, so long as the former is a valid substitution. Therefore T is always deduced as `[base-type]` when an argument (`arg`) of the form `[base-type]&&` is passed to the template function.

If the passed `arg` has the form `[base-type]&`, only rule 4 applies and `[base-type]&` must be substituted for `T`.  There is only one possibility this time.  The return type is thus...

```
 Rule 4: T + && = [base-type]& + && = [base-type]&
```

The bottom line is this:

> In every case the type returned from `std::forward<T>(arg)` is the
> collapsed version of `T&&`, which is *exactly* the same as the type of
> `arg`.

Note that this only works as long as `arg` is specified as being of type `T&&`.  Specifying `arg` as `T&` or `T` doesn't produce the desired universal forwarding, so you shouldn't ever do it.  `arg T&&` is the only universal forwarding argument specification.

I wrote a small tutorial program that can be run online here.  It demonstrates that `T&&` can represent a reference to either an l-value and an r-value.  It also shows that `T&` and `T` do not work.

[passing l-values and r-values with universal forwarding.](https://tech.io/snippet/YsxxhxV)